# Failed to reload content via Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

OK, so basically this is my issue :

- I've got a dynamic page with a table in it
- When the user clicks to delete an entry, the entry is deleted from the db and the table is reloaded (via a controller) using Ajax
- However, even when the content is re-fetched, it keeps showing the PREVIOUS version of my contents (as if the page was somehow cached?). If I reload the whole page, it shows up alright...

What could be going on?

Comment: You need to post a bit of code so we can help you debug. Please post the ajax query and callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Chrome?

I've found similar behaviours when using ajax calls on Chrome.

If you are using jQuery to do the ajax call you can use the attribute cache: false for the method ajax to avoid this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

ensure your ajax-request is not cached on the client. assuming you are using jquery, there is a setting: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ which does the magic.

use firebug or the chrome dev tools to check your request/response headers. there is might something like `cache-control` or `last-modified` which lets your browser cache the request.

any server-side cache-engines?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are getting the cached resutls. You may add a unique timestamp to your ajax call, when calling the data to reload to resolve this issue.

You may use [$.now](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.now/) function which returns a number representing the current time.

```
$("#someDiv").load("yourPage.php"+$.now());
```

Answer (score 1):

Its actually a caching related problem. So, to ensure this, just emulate fresh URI like

```
$.post("yourupdatepage.php?r="+(Math.random() * (1000 - 1) + 1), 
  ...
);
```